# Is there is function to insert text to the next line of the cursor

Tags: ckeditor5-react

How to inser text in ckeditor5 in new line next to the cursor

In ckeditor5 how to insert text in the new line where the cursor currently in. when cursor in the
2 line and press insert the text want to insert in the next line